# calculating mean and sum in pivot_table in pandas sorted by two separate desired col values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data set from 2015-2018 which has months and days as 2nd and third col like below:

```
Year    Month   Day rain    temp    humidity    snow
2015    1       1   0       20      60          0
2015    1       2   2       18      58          0
2015    1       3   0       20      62          2
2015    1       4   5       15      62          0
2015    1       5   2       18      61          1
2015    1       6   0       19      60          2
2015    1       7   3       20      59          0
2015    1       8   2       17      65          0
2015    1       9   1       17      61          0
```

I wanted to use pivot_table to calculate something like (the mean of temperature for year 2016 and months (1,2,3)

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this?

Comment: maybe `df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).temp.mean()` ?

Comment: I need specific values like winter of 2016 ... not sure it pd.groupby works that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `pd.cut` then `groupby`

```
df.temp.groupby([df.Year,pd.cut(df.Month,[0,3,6,9,12],labels=['Winter','Spring','Summer','Autumn'],right =False)]).mean()
Out[93]: 
Year  Month 
2015  Winter    18.222222
```